# Maximum Likelihood Function for uniformly distributed points

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently trying to solve Exercise 22.10 from David MacKay's Book *"Information theory, inference, and learning algorithms"*

[image]

I have absolutely no idea on how to approach this task, and would highly appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with the one-dimensional case. The probability density function of the uniform distribution on [a,b] is $\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{I}_{[a,b]}(x)$.

The above formula also represents the likelihood of *one* point. What if you had multiple points (say, N)?

For a given sample of values, we can make a likelihood based on parameters $a$ and $b$ in the same way that you would for others:

$L(\mathbf{x};a,b)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{I}_{[a,b]}(x_i) = (\frac{1}{b-a})^N\prod\limits_{i=1}^N\mathbf{I}_{[a,b]}(x_i)$

This likelihood function has the following properties:

1) If any sample value falls outside [a,b], then the likelihood becomes zero.

2) The smaller you make b-a, the higher the likelihood of the sample.

These two properties counterbalance each other. You want to make the support of the function as small as possible without excluding any values. Hence, the MLEs in the one dimensional case are: $\hat a = \min{x_i}, \hat b = \max{x_i}$

Now, for your actual problem, you can take advantage of the independence of the x and y coordinates of each star to break down your 2-D problem into two 1-D problems. Since the window is rectangular, not necessarily a square, the two directions are completely independent and you can simply multiply the likelihoods for the x and y directions to get a joint likelihood of all your parameters.

Hopefully the above gives you some ideas on how to proceed. Comment if anything confuses you.

Comment: What if there is no maximum or minimum? What if the starry sky is inifinite?

Comment: @Naji then a uniform distribution is inappropriate. As stated, there are limits due to the window, so your concern is moot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The window is limited but I don't see an indication of sky being limited in the problem. Then if that would be the case, the probabiliy of a star lying outside of the window frame will not be zero anymore, or am I being wrong on my argument?

Comment: @Naji The problem is not asking about the likelihood of finding a star within a window. It is asking about the likelihood that the window has a particualr length and width *given* that the coordinates of the observed stars are jointly uniformly distributed over the area of the window. The assumption is that any finite area of sky exhibits a uniform distribution of star locations. Also, note that the sky is not infinite: you can paramaterize it using spherical coordinates with the radius set arbitarily to 1. X,Y coords only work here due to small scale linearity of a spherical surface.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I think what you mentioned in your second sentence is posterior distribution and not likelihood. This is the real question(I imagine including the poster) that we are supposed to solve:
http://i57.tinypic.com/11aigm1.png

About your second note, I was being hypothetical but you need a stereographic projection to make it an infinite plain.

Comment: @Naji a distribution and likelihood have the same form. However, we are not calculating the distribution of parameters but the likelihood of a sample given an assumed distribution (posterior or whatever you want to call it). Anyway, the question explicitly talks about likelihood, not a posteriod distribution on the parameters. What would your prior be?

Comment: I ma not following, but thanks for replying. Anyway your answer inspired me to write my own version. Vote up! Thank you very much:)